# Does $an = bn \mod mn \implies a = b \mod mn$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, integers

Let $m,n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $m, n\geq 1$. Then can we say that
$$ an = bn \mod mn \implies a = b \mod mn?$$

Comment: No, but $an = bn \mod mn \implies a = b \mod m.$

Comment: @ReinerMartin That is actually the property I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the given mod equation is equivalent to $$an=bn+kmn$$ where $k$ is a integer number, then we have $$n(a-b-km)=0$$ if $n=0$ then the given equation is true, in the other case we get
$$a-b=km$$ or $$a\equiv b\mod m$$

Answer (score 0):

No. As a counterexample take $a=0, b=1, m=1, n=2$.

Comment: What about if $a$ and $b$ are strictly less than $m$ and $n$?

Answer (score 0):

If you had tried an example or two, I'm certain you would've discovered the answer yourself. For instance, $a = 2, b = 4, m = 2, n = 3$ gives
$$
2\cdot 3\equiv 4\cdot 3\mod{2\cdot 3}\quad\text{This is true}\\
2\equiv 4\mod{2\cdot 3}\quad\text{This is not}
$$

Comment: Is this also not true for $a, b$ strictly less than $m,n$?

Comment: @LukeCollins As is pointed out in the answer by Sonnhard Graubner, and the comment by Reiner Martin, we do have $a\equiv b \mod m$. So if $0\leq a, b<m$, then we necessarily have $a = b$, so $a\equiv b$ modulo anything. The size of $n$ doesn't matter (you could make $n = 9$ in my example, for instance).

Comment: Thank you -- It sufficed for my purposes that they were congruent $\bmod m$.